# Matching only outermost blocks with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in C# that will match PL/SQL blocks where there is an **outermost** `END;` without a trailing forward slash, since these cause the scripts to exit silently at that point when run with SQLPlus.

So, for example, this should trigger the regular expression:

```
BEGIN
END;
```

and this should **not** trigger it:

```
BEGIN
END;
/
```

But nested `BEGIN`...`END` blocks don't need the slash, so the following should **not** be a match:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    END;
    -- no trailing slash here, and that's fine
END;
/
```

It feels like balancing groups should be able to handle this. I want to match "END;" if it's not followed by optional whitespace and a forward slash, but only for an outermost block.

I've tried some variations on the following, but it isn't quite there:

```
var trigger = new Regex(            
    @"(?<keyword>BEGIN).*?(?<-keyword>END;)(?(keyword)(\s*/))",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

I've found lots of examples showing how to find unbalanced parentheses, but none that are trying to restrict patterns to just the points where the begin and end tags *are* balanced.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with a regex?

Comment: To be clear, in your last example, do you want to match the innermost BEGIN/END or not?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte No. With the three examples, I want IsMatch() to be true for the first one and false for the others.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there can be multiple outer blocks in sequence. I want the regex to be matched if any of those are missing the forward slash.

Comment: I think the more simple approach is to describe the two cases (with and without the final slash) and to put the final slash in an optional capture group. Then you test if this group is defined or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with, based heavily on Camimir et Hippolyte's answer:

```
(?xi)
^([^B]|B(?!EGIN))*                # chomp everything before the first BEGIN
(?>                               # possible content in a block
    (?<c>  \bBEGIN\b) [^BE]* |
    (?<-c> \bEND;   ) [^BE]* |
    \b[BE]+           [^BE]* |
    B(?!EGIN\b)       [^BE]* |
    E(?!ND;)          [^BE]*
)*?
(?<-c>\bEND;)                     # pop closing END; off the stack
(?(c)(?!))                        # only match outer blocks
\s*                               # ignore whitespace between END; and /
([^/ \t\n\r]|$)                   # it's a match if there is no trailing /
```

This avoids the need to do any post-processing of groups: either `IsMatch` is true and there's a missing `/` or it's false and there isn't. This fits in better with the framework I'm trying to slot this into (admittedly not explained well in my question).

It's also important to anchor the search to the first BEGIN. If it's free to float then it can fall back to matching nested BEGIN...END blocks, which confused me for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to match all outermost blocks without exceptions, then to determine which one isn't followed by a slash, you only need to test for each result which one has an empty capture group 1.

The pattern with the *ignore Whitespace* option:

```
(?xi)
\bBEGIN\b [^BE]*
(?> # possible content in a block
    (?<c>  \bBEGIN\b) [^BE]* |
    (?<-c> \bEND;   ) [^BE]* |
    \B[BE]+     [^BE]* |
    B(?!EGIN\b) [^BE]* |
    E(?!ND;)    [^BE]*
)*?
(?(c)(?!)) # <-- perhaps better if you exchange these
\bEND;     # <-- two lines in real world
\s*
(/?) # optional
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fx)%5CbBEGIN%5Cb%5B%5EBE%5D*(%3F%3E(%3F%3Cc%3E%5CbBEGIN%5Cb)%5B%5EBE%5D*%7C(%3F%3C-c%3E%5CbEND%20%20%20%3B)%5B%5EBE%5D*%7C%5CB%5BBE%5D%2B%5B%5EBE%5D*%7CB(%3F!EGIN%5Cb)%5B%5EBE%5D*%7CE(%3F!ND%3B)%5B%5EBE%5D*)*%3F(%3F(c)(%3F!))%5CbEND%3B%5Cs*(%2F)%3F&i=BEGIN%0D%0AEND%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aand%20this%20should%20not%20trigger%20it%3A%0D%0A%0D%0ABEGIN%0D%0AEND%3B%0D%0A%2F%0D%0A%0D%0ABut%20nested%20BEGIN...END%20blocks%20don%27t%20need%20the%20slash%2C%20so%20the%20following%20should%20not%20be%20a%20match%3A%0D%0A%0D%0ABEGIN%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BEGIN%0D%0A%20%20%20%20END%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20--%20no%20trailing%20slash%20here%2C%20and%20that%27s%20fine%0D%0AEND%3B%0D%0A%2F) click on "Table" to see what I mean.